# Strange highlight Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, html, css, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have some problem with the highlight.

This is my CSS code:

```
html {
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        }
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript: location.href = 'level://?id=123456';">
    <div class="Box" id="Box0">
        <table class="BoldText" style="margin:8px;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="50">
                    <div class="ProfileImage">
                        <div style="background:url(<url>) top left no-repeat;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>gustaf98 published a level
                    <div style="width:220px; margin-top:4px;" class="lightText">Skiftnyckel</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</a>
```

And this is the result when I touch the box on my iPhone in a UIWebView:

[image: Preview]

And my question are, how can I get the black highlight over the whole box?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have this applied to the entire HTML rather than a specific container according to your CSS.  Do you have a working example of this, or a link?

Try applying it specifically to the box that you want to be highlighted.

For example...

```
.box {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    }
```